# What percentage of Trump supporters believed that Mexico will literally pay for the construction of the border wall?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, trump-wall

According to a [recent comment](https://www.cnn.com/2019/01/10/politics/trump-mexico-pay-wall/index.html) by President Trump:

> "When during the campaign, I would say 'Mexico is going to pay for it,' obviously, I never said this, and I never meant they're gonna write out a check, I said they're going to pay for it. They are," he said as he prepared to depart the White House for the southern border.

Are there statistics somewhere on the percentage of Trump supporters who believed that Mexico will literally write a check to pay for the wall?

Comment: I don't have any statistics, but based on the chatter on Twitter it does not appear that many Trump folks took the comments as Mexico would cut a check for building the wall or pay directly. I think most folks assumed it would come out of the foreign aid that the government pays them. Which does not appear to be the case either

Comment: It's worth pointing out, he said exactly that and [went so far as to outline how it would work](https://apps.washingtonpost.com/g/page/politics/memo-explains-how-donald-trump-plans-to-pay-for-border-wall/2007/).

Comment: I would bet near zero.  If anyone really though Mexico was just going to send us a pile of cash, then...wow.  I have always just assumed that the US would find a roundabout way to make it happen.

Comment: @acpilot Mexico is paying the wall by the trade deals. Mexico is indeed paying for the wall. I don't understand your points. The wall is financed by Mexico, like how you invest a business then charge your clients. Have you done business?

Comment: @SmallChess if Mexico is paying the wall, then why do the Democrats need to sign off on funding for the wall? If Mexico is already paying, surely it should have to be paid for by the US budget?

Comment: I think you have to clarify this.  Are you asking about people who really thought that Mexico would literally pay for the wall (and indeed, that Trump would actually try to have it built), or about those who thought that Trump really believed that he could get Mexito to cut a check?

Comment: @JonathanReez Do you accept or refute the fact that the document [Memo explains how Donald Trump plans to pay for border wall](https://apps.washingtonpost.com/g/page/politics/memo-explains-how-donald-trump-plans-to-pay-for-border-wall/2007/) linked to by [Schwern](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/5272/schwern) is a verified secondary source, distributed to the Washington Post by the primary source? Does the linked document _"specify what "paying for the wall" really means."_ from the primary source?

Comment: @jamesqf to clarify I'm asking for the percentage of US citizens who: a) believed that the wall will be built b) believed that the wall will be built *and* that Mexico will make a direct payment to cover the cost

Comment: @JonathanReez The current language at the question is "literally write a check", not "Mexico will make a direct payment to cover the cost". Are those terms intended to be synonymous? What instruments are included within "direct payment"?  "believed" is past tense. What is the time range that you are interested in?

Comment: @guest271314: Accepting that the document is an actual memo from Trump, we still have to deal with the issue of belief.  After all, the man has been known to tell lies.

Comment: @jamesqf If that document is accepted as a primary source distributed to the secondary source that published the material, there is no "belief" involved. There are only facts. Relevant to this question: Is "Mexico will literally write a check" synonymous with "Make a one-time payment of $5-10 billion"? As pointed out at this users answer. Why is belief irrelevant? If the document is the primary source, there is no controversy. We have the facts. If an an individual fails to read the primary document but instead relies on "what they heard" they are subject to believe anything anyone tells them.

Comment: @SmallChess you said what I said.  We're saying the same thing.  And yes, I've "done business."  Business is my business, after all.  Give me liberty, or give me business.  BUSINESS!!!!

Comment: @guest271314: Belief is relevant to the question because that is the question.  E.g. I can say the the planet Nibiru is going to destroy Earth.  That is objectively false, yet you can find a number of people who believe it.  Likewise, it is objectively false that Mexico would pay for the Wall, but doubtless some people believed that it would.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of mid-December 2018, 59% of Republicans thought it was '[very likely](https://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/athena/files/2018/12/21/5c1d390ce4b05c88b6f894a4.pdf)' that Trump would get Mexico to pay for the wall (question 6A), and 9% believe he has 'already accomplished' this.

As a comparison, in April of 2017, only 46% of Republicans thought it was '[very likely](http://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/tabsHP100Days20170426.pdf)' (question 4), [47% in November of 2017](http://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/tabsHPCampaignpromises20171101.pdf) (question 6), and in March of 2018, [it was up to 54%](http://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/tabsHPTrumppolicies20180328.pdf) (question 6A). So if anything, Republicans increasingly think he's going to be able to make Mexico pay for it.

As for specific method? [Fox News is probably the best source](https://insider.foxnews.com/2016/04/05/donald-trump-reveals-how-he-would-make-mexico-pay-border-wall) you'll get, and they cite [the memorandum](https://www.washingtonpost.com/apps/g/page/politics/memo-explains-how-donald-trump-plans-to-pay-for-border-wall/2007/?tid=a_inl_manual) Trump sent out.

Comment: Dunno why the downvote. This seems like a clear enough answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Maybe the "Fox news is probably the best source you'll get" syntax evoked a involuntary, reflexive reaction.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Here's one poll by Quinnipiac University, see this [link.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2017/08/25/most-americans-dont-want-the-wall-dont-think-mexico-will-pay-for-it-and-dont-believe-it-will-happen/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.13b212067b72) The poll suggests that a majority of Republicans believed Mexico would pay for the wall.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't specify what "paying for the wall" really means.

Comment: @JonathanReez "...what "paying for the wall" really means." I think most people have an intuitive understanding of "paying for the wall" even if in the end it's not completely accurate.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only one poll and polls can be quite inaccurate. One could for example ask how the poll was conducted, how any people were asked, ... to get a better picture of a possible error margin. A few more details are at https://poll.qu.edu/national/release-detail?ReleaseID=2457

Comment: The link in this answer also contains the results of a CBS poll from around the same time frame which asks "If the wall were built, who would end up paying?" - respondents overwhelmingly believed the US would foot the bill. Even for Republicans, less than 25% believed that Mexico would end up paying. Why show us one graph and not the other? Seems like a bit of cherry-picking.

Comment: @Trilarion - I think you'll find as Trump's bluster about this turns into walking back statements, denying he said things, and redefining the term, people who are invested in never having to say they or Trump might be wrong will see their "intuitive understanding" shift considerably.

Comment: @Trilarion, I don't think most adults have an "intuitive understanding" of what "paying for the wall" means.  Most adults who have used credit cards know that even though it is a credit card company that pays for a purchase, it is still them who pay for it in the end.  And since most adults have used credit cards, the idea that "who pays for it in the end is what matters" is not lost on them.

Comment: @grovkin That is exactly what I mean by paying and what I assumed everyone else also understands. I'm actually very surprised that paying may not be defined as "who pays for it in the end" by anyone (except Mr. Trump maybe, but he was not asked in this poll likely).